# How I can remove every line that starts with "//" on an std::string?

Tags: c++, stdstring

I have the following template std::string

```
std::string myString = R"svg(
  <svg height={size} width={size}>
    <rect {...rectProps} x={x0h} y={y0h} />
    // <rect {...rectProps} x={x1h} y={y0h} />
    <rect {...rectProps} x={x0h} y={y1h} />
    // <rect {...rectProps} x={x1h} y={y1h} />
  </svg>
)svg";
```

And I will like to remove every line that starts with //

So the result I want will be like this

```
<svg height={size} width={size}>
  <rect {...rectProps} x={x0h} y={y0h} />
  <rect {...rectProps} x={x0h} y={y1h} />
</svg>
```

Edit: So my idea now is to iterate each line, trim it, and then detect if it starts with "//"

So far I have this in pseudo

```
std::istringstream stream(myString);
std::string line;
std::string myFinalString;
while (std::getline(stream, line)) {
  // TODO: trim line first
  bool isComment = false; // Find here if the line starts with //
  if (!isComment) {
    myFinalString += line + "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Here's a simple way to figure out how to do this, and it never fails to work. Just take out a blank sheet of paper. Write down using short, simple sentences in plain English, a step-by-step process of doing this. When done, [call your rubber duck for an appointment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). We don't write code for other people, on Stackoverflow. We always refer such questions to your rubber duck. After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++. Mission accomplished!

Comment: You can remove spaces with [boost::algorith::trim](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/boost/algorithm/string/trim.hpp) and check for `"//"` with [boost::algorith::starts_with](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/starts_with.html)

Comment: " but is not working as I expect" is not a useful comment. Better is to tell what outcome you get and what you would expect. Also include possible error messages.

Comment: @ThomasSablik is the something like this for std::string?

Comment: Is "every line" contained in a file or do you want to remove lines from the source code directly?

Comment: they are inside an std::string not a file

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thanks for the feedback, I edited the post with more info

Comment: @ellipticaldoor There are many ways, you can do this. Using `std::string::find()` may help in identifying these lines, but doesn't guarantee, that there's nothing else before the `"//"`. Another way is simply using `std::istringstream`, the `operator>>()`will already filter whitespaces when reading. `std::regex` might be more reliable for parsing. BTW: XML comments usually look like `<!-- comment -->`, not `// comment`.

Comment: Read up on regex. This will find your lines: \s//.*$

Answer (score 1):

The simplest you can do is using regex library:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::string myString = R"svg(
    <svg height={size} width={size}>
        <rect {...rectProps} x={x0h} y={y0h} />
        // <rect {...rectProps} x={x1h} y={y0h} />
        <rect {...rectProps} x={x0h} y={y1h} />
        // <rect {...rectProps} x={x1h} y={y1h} />
    </svg>
    )svg";
    
    std::cout << myString << std::endl; //before
    std::string new_string = std::regex_replace(myString, std::regex("\n *//.*\n"), "\n");
    std::cout << new_string << std::endl; //after
}
```

We catch all patterns which start with new line `\n`, have zero of more spaces  `*`, two slashes `//` and zero or more any characters `.*` ending with another new line. We replace occurrences with just a new line (to compensate one of them).

The output:

```
<svg height={size} width={size}>
    <rect {...rectProps} x={x0h} y={y0h} />
    // <rect {...rectProps} x={x1h} y={y0h} />
    <rect {...rectProps} x={x0h} y={y1h} />
    // <rect {...rectProps} x={x1h} y={y1h} />
</svg>


<svg height={size} width={size}>
    <rect {...rectProps} x={x0h} y={y0h} />
    <rect {...rectProps} x={x0h} y={y1h} />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

> is not working as I expect

It definitely doesn't work the way you except it to.
The overload of `erase` you use looks like

```
string& erase( size_type index = 0, size_type count = npos);
```

Description of the overload from cppreference:

> Removes min(count, size() - index) characters starting at index.

So what you really do by `svg.erase(0, svg.find("//") + 1)` is you erase all the characters from index [0] up to [index of the last `'/'` you found]

Instead you should do the following:

1. Search for `"//"` in your string, name this position A.
2. Search for `'\n'` in your string, name this position B.
3. Erase interval [A; B] from the string or [A; svg.length()] if you didn't find B
4. Repeat until there is no more position A

P.s. I'd recommend to search from the end rather than from beginning because it would be easier to erase a piece form string if it is closer to the end than to the beginning

P.p.s. Also be sure to use iterators if you want to remove exactly intervals because the only overload of `erase` that removes intervals is

```
iterator erase( const_iterator first, const_iterator last );
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [std::basic_string::erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) based on the number of `'/'` found by [std::basic_string::find_first_not_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of) is hard to beat for simplicity, e.g.

```
    std::string s { "//Some comment" };
    
    if (s.at(0) == '/')
        s.erase (0, s.find_first_not_of ("/"));
```

You can also remove any leading whitespace before the `"//"` by adding `" \t"` to the reject characters:

```
    std::string s { "  //Some comment" };
    
    if (s.at(s.find_first_not_of (" \t/") - 1) == '/')
        s.erase (0, s.find_first_not_of (" \t/"));
```

(**note:** the `- 1` is necessary with `at()` as it expects a zero-based index, while `erase()` expects a count of characters to remove)

Then to handle leading and trailing whitespace surrounding `"//"` you could `#include <cctype>` and use `isspace(c)` as follows:

```
    std::string s { "  //  Some comment" };
    char c = s.at(s.find_first_not_of (" \t/") - 1);
    
    if (c == '/' || isspace (c))
        s.erase (0, s.find_first_not_of (" \t/"));
```

In all cases `"Some comment"` is the result.

Answer (score -1):

In the end this was the solution I found

```
std::string trim(const std::string &str) {
  size_t first = str.find_first_not_of(' ');
  if (std::string::npos == first) {
    return str;
  }
  size_t last = str.find_last_not_of(' ');
  return str.substr(first, (last - first + 1));
}

bool startsWith(const std::string &input, const std::string &start) {
  return input.find(start) != std::string::npos;
}

std::string myString = R"svg(
  <svg height={size} width={size}>
    <rect {...rectProps} x={x0h} y={y0h} />
    // <rect {...rectProps} x={x1h} y={y0h} />
    <rect {...rectProps} x={x0h} y={y1h} />
    // <rect {...rectProps} x={x1h} y={y1h} />
  </svg>
)svg";

std::istringstream stream(myString);
std::string line;
std::string myFinalString;
while (std::getline(stream, trim(line))) {
  if (!startsWith(line, "//")) {
    myFinalString += line + "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `startsWith()` is not quite correct and would returm false positive when there is "//" inside string not at the beginning. It should be `input.find(start) == 0` instead.